# SQL Join, Exclude Rows

Tags: sql, join

This is probably something really easy but I cant figure it out at the moment.
Currently I am struggling with removing duplicate rows from my data set. Below i have added my current result but i am only interested in the Green Rows.
Any help/support would be very much appreciated.

Best Regards
Ciao

***Code***

```
SELECT
d.awb_no, 
e.piece_id,
e.event_day, 
e.event_cd, 
d.calc_piece_no

FROM OPS_DW.detail AS d 

    JOIN OPS_DW.event AS e 
    ON d.rec_key = e.rec_key 

WHERE e.event_day between 20200120 and 20200125
And d.awb_no = 1568275645
AND e.event_cd In ('PD','OK')
```

***Result***
[image: This is the Result i am getting]

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) SQL result sets don't have a color, so please explain the logic that you re trying to implement.

Comment: Define "duplicate row". Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PSWhen you get a result that you don't expect, find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first erroneous subexpression & its input & output. (Debugging fundamental.) ] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you want a prioritization query, with "PD" rows, if available and otherwise "OK" rows -- basedon the `awb_no`/`event_day` combination.  If so, one relatively simple method uses `NOT EXISTS`:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT d.awb_no, e.piece_id, e.event_day, e.event_cd,  d.calc_piece_no
      FROM OPS_DW.detail d JOIn
           OPS_DW.event AS e 
           ON d.rec_key = e.rec_key 
      WHERE e.event_day between 20200120 and 20200125 AND
           d.awb_no = 1568275645
           e.event_cd In ('PD','OK')
     )
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE t.event_cd = 'PD' OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM t t2
                  WHERE t2.awb_no = t.awb_no AND
                        t2.event_day = t.event_day AND
                        t2.event_cd = 'PD' 
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `DISTINCT`. It will eliminate duplicate rows .

```
SELECT
d.awb_no, 
e.piece_id,
e.event_day, 
e.event_cd, 
d.calc_piece_no

FROM OPS_DW.detail AS d 

    JOIN OPS_DW.event AS e 
    ON d.rec_key = e.rec_key 

WHERE e.event_day between 20200120 and 20200125
And d.awb_no = 1568275645
AND e.event_cd In ('PD','OK');
```

Comment: You didn't use distinct. But anyway although the question is not clear what seems clear is that when it says duplicate row it doesn't mean duplicate row. Unclear questions merit comments asking for clarity & downvotes & close votes, not answers. Also code-only answers are typically poor, explain why particular code answers a particular question.